# How can I write headers with spaces using CsvHelper?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am using the CsvHelper library to generate a CSV file from an `IEnumerable<Person>`, where `Person` is a basic class.

```
public class Person
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I need to write quoted headers, i.e. instead of "DisplayName", the column in the resulting file should be "Display Name".

How can I do this?

Comment: C#? Something else?

Answer (score 9):

Create a `ClassMap`.

```
void Main()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
    {
        var records = new List<Person>
        {
            new Test { DisplayName = "one", Age = 1},
            new Test { DisplayName = "two", Age = 2 },
        };
        
        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<PersonMap>();
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
        
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public sealed class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.DisplayName).Name("Display Name");
        Map(m => m.Age);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Display Name,Age
one,1
two,2
```

Comment: Is there a way this can be made generic?

Comment: What do you mean by generic?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, is there a way *including space in compound word properties* can be handled generically/automatically (for any object) instead of writing custom mappers. For e.g. property `AccountType` should correspond to header `Account Type`. While reading this is possible by setting a property on CsvReader. But for writing we have none.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. In the ClassMap my field is mapped with a Map(m => m.ReportingGroup).Name("Reporting Group"), but the written header becomes "ReportingGroup". I'll post a separate question.

Comment: @nawfal I would suggest asking on the github issues.https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues

Comment: For anyone trying this out in 2019 you will need to change "CsvClassMap<Person>" to "ClassMap<Person>"

Answer (score 0):

I had no headers with workaround, so I did this quick workaround instead:

```
foreach (var property in typeof(MyCsvClass).GetProperties())
{
  csvWriter.WriteField(property.Name.Replace('_', ' '));
}
csvWriter.NextRecord();
csvWriter.WriteRecords(models);
```

This takes the property names and replace underscore with space, so I could just name the properties with underscores instead of spaces, and it mapped correctly.

It requires, however, that you use the `HasHeaderRecord = false` option on the CsvWriter.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the header names with [Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/reflection-and-attributes/)

Example with Person:

```
using CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes;

public class Person
{
    [Name("Display Name")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    [Name("Age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Another Example:

```
using CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes;

public class CompanyExportData
{
    [Name("Company Code")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; } = "Store";
    [Name("Employee Number")]
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    [Name("Primary Email Address")]
    public string PrimaryEmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

[From the CSVHelper docs on how to use Attributes](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/attributes/)